# Converting std::array to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, stdarray

In the code below, the size of the function (foo) argument (`std::vector`) can be anything to make the function a generic one. However, sometimes the size container is known so std::array can be used. The problem is to convert the `std::array` to `std::vector`. What is the best way to solve this problem? Is it better to just use `std::vector` always in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// generic function: size of the container can be anything
void foo (vector<int>& vec)
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
   array<int,3> arr; // size is known. why use std::vector?
   foo (arr); // cannot convert std::array to std::vector

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that `foo` modifies the vector since it takes by mutable reference, is that correct?  That's going to be very relevant to the answer.

Comment: For now you'll have to work around it, but in the future we'll write something like `void foo(RangeOf<int>&);` and it'll take any kind of range of `int`s.

Comment: This problem is why the standard library always takes `begin` and `end` iterators. That way it doesn't care which container you use.

Comment: `// size is known. why use std::vector?` -- why **not** use `std::vector`?

Comment: You could write a wrapper type like [llvm::MutableArrayRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1MutableArrayRef.html)

Answer (score 16):

Given that you pass in an `array`, `foo` does not seem to resize the container it gets passed in (however, it does seem to modify the elements since `vec` is passed non-const). It therefore does not need to know anything about the underlying container other than how to access elements.

Then, you can **pass a pair of iterators** (and make the iterator type a template argument), as many STL algorithms do.

Comment: Also, If you want to avoid making it a template, the parameters could be a `int* first` and a `size_t count`

Comment: @MooingDuck: `int *begin, int *end` would be C++isher than `int *first, size_t count`.

Comment: Does the STL support the concept of a range? (a pair of iterators), or do I have to manually get begin(), end()?

Answer (score 0):

The function accepts a vector by reference. So there is no any sense to pass an object of type std::array to the function. It could have a sense if the parameter of the function would be defined as const reference to a vector.